# Asteroid Game Clone P5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am making an Asteroid Game in JavaScript using the P5.js library.

I need help with the fourth step, which is mentioned below.

***Step 4*****:** In sketch.js, complete the inside () function that takes the location of two circles and their diameters and returns true if they overlap and false otherwise. You could check it works by creating a dummy circle around the mouse and checking if inside () returns true.

The problem with my code is it only returns false when the circles do not overlap, but when the circle overlaps, nothing is returned to my console.

My code for the sketch.js file is below.

```
var dummySize;
var mouseVector;
 
function setup() {
  dummySize = createVector(50, 50); // Size of the dummy circle
  mouseVector = createVector(); // Initialize mouseVector 
}
 
function draw() {
  // Update mouseVector with current mouse position
  mouseVector.set(mouseX, mouseY);
 
  //Check if circles overlap and print message
  var overlap = isInside(mouseVector, dummySize, earthLoc, earthSize);
 
  if(overlap) 
  {
    console.log('True');
  }
  else
  {
    console.log('False');
  }
 
  checkCollisions(spaceship, asteroids); // function that checks collision between various elements
}
 
function isInside(locA, sizeA, locB, sizeB) 
{
  var distBetweenCenters = dist(locA.x, locA.y, locB.x, locB.y);
  var radiiSum = sizeA.x/2 + sizeB.x/2;
  var overlap = distBetweenCenters <= radiiSum;
  return overlap;
}
```

Comment: in your code you haven't defined `earthLoc` and `earthSize`. Could you post a minimal reproducible problem that we can run? thanks